# How to use group by on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas for some data processing, My panda statement looks like this

```
yearage.groupby(['year', 'Tm']).size()
```

It gives me data like this

```
2014  ATL     9
      BOS     9
      BRK     7
      CHI    10
      CHO     9
      CLE     8
      DAL     9
      DEN     8
      DET     9
      GSW     8
```

When I convert it into dataframe, I get only two columns compound key and the count. What I actually want is, three columns,

```
year, Tm, Size
```

How do I separate out the two compound keys after `groupby`?

Comment: How do you convert to `df`? By `reset_index()`?

Comment: It's a `Series`, which you can convert to a `DataFrame` via `reset_index()`.

Comment: Just to briefly elaborate on the prior comments, you have a MulitIndex rather than flat index there b/c  you grouped on multiple columns.  reset_index just takes you from `['year','tm']` index to standard `range(x)` index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify `as_index=False` in your groupby statement.  As a side note, you probably want to use count (which excludes NaNs) instead of size.

```
>>> df.groupby(['year', 'Tm'], as_index=False).count()
   year   Tm  a
0  2014  ATL  4
1  2014  BOS  4
2  2014  BRK  1
3  2014  CHI  1
4  2014  CHO  1
5  2014  CLE  1
6  2014  DAL  1
7  2014  DEN  1
8  2014  DET  1
9  2014  GSW  1
```

For size:

> Another simple aggregation example is to compute the size of each group. This is included in GroupBy as the size method. It returns a Series whose index are the group names and whose values are the sizes of each group.

For count:

> Compute count of group, excluding missing values

Comment: I was thinking of that same answer but tried it and it didn't work for size(), and I didn't realize it would work for count().  Not sure why behavior differs between size and count?

Comment: Very odd.  I get the same result, except that it sets 'year' and 'Tm' as my MultiIndex when I use `size` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name` for new column name `Size`:

```
yearage.groupby(['year','Tm']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
```

Sample:

```
print yearage
    year   Tm   a
0   2014  ATL   9
1   2014  ATL   9
2   2014  ATL   9
3   2014  ATL   9
4   2014  BOS   9
5   2014  BRK   7
6   2014  BOS   9
7   2014  BOS   9
8   2014  BOS   9
9   2014  CHI  10
10  2014  CHO   9
11  2014  CLE   8
12  2014  DAL   9
13  2014  DEN   8
14  2014  DET   9
15  2014  GSW   8

print yearage.groupby(['year','Tm']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
   year   Tm  Size
0  2014  ATL     4
1  2014  BOS     4
2  2014  BRK     1
3  2014  CHI     1
4  2014  CHO     1
5  2014  CLE     1
6  2014  DAL     1
7  2014  DEN     1
8  2014  DET     1
9  2014  GSW     1
```

Without parameter `name` get new column `0`:

```
print yearage.groupby(['year','Tm']).size().reset_index()
   year   Tm  0
0  2014  ATL  4
1  2014  BOS  4
2  2014  BRK  1
3  2014  CHI  1
4  2014  CHO  1
5  2014  CLE  1
6  2014  DAL  1
7  2014  DEN  1
8  2014  DET  1
9  2014  GSW  1
```